When were the types of linkage and the types of object equivalent?
I came across the following excerpt in Chapter 4 of The C Book and was wondering which edition of the language was being referred to by the part in bold:

It's confusing that the types of linkage and the types of object are both described by the terms ‘internal’ and ‘external’; this is to some extent historical. C archaeologists may know that at one time the two were equivalent and one implied the other—for us it's unfortunate that the terms remain but the meanings have diverged.

Also, did internal linkage have the same meaning back then as it does today?

Maybe https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration could provide the details/nuances to answer the first part of your question?

I am not sure what the author means with "types of object" being described with "internal" or "external". I haven't heard that. Does the book provide any explanation or example? What is the type in this context?

Ignore it as it refers to the paleontological pre-standard language version. Do not even bother to understand it unless you write a "C history and prehistory" article


I [...] was wondering which edition of the language was being referred to by the part in bold:

It's confusing that the types of linkage and the types of object are both described by the terms ‘internal’ and ‘external’; this is to some extent historical. C archaeologists may know that at one time the two were equivalent and one implied the other


TL;DR: This is a better characterization of C's predecessor, B, than of any "edition" of C.

Interpreting the quotation
First, the quotation is a bit confusing without more context.  Its "type of object" does not mean data type, but rather:

There are essentially two types of object in C: the internal and external objects. The distinction between external and internal is to do with functions: anything declared outside a function is external, anything inside one, including its formal parameters, is internal.

Aside: they should have said "anything defined outside a function [...]".
This is an historical usage of the terms "external" and "internal", as I'll discuss in more detail. It is not widely used any longer, however, being inconsistent with the terminology used by every version of the ISO C language specification. There remain "external" objects and function definitions in modern terminology, but these refer specifically to external linkage.  I rarely, if ever, see "internal" applied to functions or objects in contemporary writing, but in such writing I would interpret it as referring to internal linkage, not to being defined at block scope.
C's predecessor, B
C was derived from an earlier language, B.
One of B's distinctions from some other languages of its era was a provision for variables, within functions, that do not have storage permanently assigned for them.  These were aptly called "automatic", which term persists in modern C's "automatic storage duration".  B's other, global, objects had permanently assigned storage, sometimes described as "static" storage as in modern "static storage duration", and they could be referenced from other source files. Thus they were external in terms both of visibility across source units and of lexical placement with respect to function definitions.  The language had a keyword extrn used in conjunction with them, so it seems clear that these were called "external".
Here, then, we have the word "external" implying both linkage and definition scope, both distinguished from a single alternative.  I don't find any direct evidence of the term "internal" being used to describe the B alternative, however, and there was nothing corresponding to C "internal linkage". But there is every reason to believe that the same "external" terminology, at least, was carried over to the earliest developmental versions of C.
Early C
Some of our best references for terminology used in the early days of C are the 1st edition of K&R3 (1978) and Dennis Ritchie's 1993 conference paper describing the development of C.4
These document that in early C, the terms "internal" and "external" were used to describe whether objects were defined inside a function (internal) or outside (external).  This "external" is consistent with the usage in B context, though with a different focus, and this "internal" is the direct complement.  C has never had internal functions in this sense, but it has always had internal objects, having inherited that feature from B.
The first edition of K&R was the earliest complete formal specification of the C language intended for public consumption.  In that version there was already a distinction between external functions and objects visible to other source files and those visible only within their own source files.  It didn't describe this as "external linkage" vs. "internal linkage", as we do now, but if I can be excused for combining terms from different eras, external objects and functions did not necessarily have external linkage.  There was already a distinction.
Internal objects in this sense have always had what we now call "no linkage", never internal linkage.  By this time there was an option to give them static storage duration, like all external objects have.  That is, there was also a distinction between linkage and storage duration for these.
Conclusion
There is nothing that we can reasonably call an "edition" of the C language in which linkage and lexical definition scope had the kind of equivalence your book claims.  That's a reasonable characterization of B, and probably of early developmental C, but it predates even the outdated version of "external" / "internal" terminology used in the earliest public specification of C and in your book.  Attributing it to C as something that "C archaeologists" might know seems misleading.
Side Note
I've read The C Book, and I like it, but it's pretty dated.  You would be better off relying on something more recent.

1"B Language Reference", https://www.thinkage.ca/gcos/expl/b/manu/manu.html.
2B. W. Kernighan, "A TUTORIAL INTRODUCTION TO THE LANGUAGE B", https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/btut.pdf.
3Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie, "The C Programming Language", 1978, ISBN: 978-0131101630.
4Dennis M. Ritchie, "The Development of the C Language", 1993, https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html.
